# NpgSQL Connection String in web.config ASP.NET

Tags: connection-string, npgsql

I am trying to get my Connection String working with NpgSQL

In my web.config I have this as my Connection String:

```
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;User ID=postgres;Password=MyPassword;Database=MyDB" providerName="Npgsql"/>
```

I also went out to NuGet and installed the NpgSQL package
and I have this Assembly in my web.config as well

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

Then I went into my .cs and added this:

```
using System.Data; using System.Data.SqlClient;using System.Data.Services.Client;using Npgsql;
```

I also have the connection identified as well in my.cs `NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);`

But when I run the function to fill in a Gridview:

```
    DataTable dtSvces = new DataTable ();
        string selctstmt = "SELECT * FROM tblapptdates";
        NpgsqlCommand  populate = new NpgsqlCommand (selctstmt, con);
        //SqlCommand populate = new SqlCommand (selctstmt, con);
        con.Open();
        NpgsqlDataAdapter Adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter (populate);
        //SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter (populate);
        Adapter.Fill (dtSvces);
        gvappts.DataSource = dtSvces;
        gvappts.DataBind ();
        con.Close ();
```

Nothing loads as if the connection is not working, No errors just the Gridview is blank.

I tested this in a MSSQL environment and I get the gridview to show results. But I want to use Postgres and I cant seem to get the results

What is missing from connectionstring? I scoured the internet and tried a few solution but none seem to work..

Comment: I Updated my function abit to to make sure I am using the NpgsqlCommand and rebuilt the application . But still the GridView does not populate. no errors. however.

Comment: I would also like to mention my Postgres SQL in on a Ubuntu 16.04 OS --Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using an NpgsqlConnection or SqlConnection? Your question shows SqlConnection, but that would only work with SQL server, not Npgsql.

Comment: Yes I am using NpgsqlConnection, I double checked my .cs .  I updated my question. I am using Ubutnu 16.04 with Apache as my web server with the mono-mod. Finally with postgres 9.5.  The page loads and my code fires. But  the gridview is not filled, I pinned it down to I think the problem is connection but I am not sure where I am getting it wrong. I read through the npgsql docs, but everything seems to be correct. as far as I can tell. --Thanks

Comment: I did notice this error in my Appache Log: